# HTML Radio buttons crash JavaScript form function

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm working on a form sight that submits to a server to be converted to a text file. The sight needs to post the data to the server side php. It also needs to add "?PART_NO=*part*&frm=MF001" to the URL to name each text file. 
If the form contains more than one radio button, it crashes the JavaScript. It's probably because of the way I'm attempting to access the form element. I only need access to the text field with the name "Part_No".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="test" method="post" action="http://10.0.0.252/test.php" onsubmit="process()">
<input type="checkbox"  tabindex="40"  id="form67_1" data-objref="458 0 R" name="box_brown" imageName="1/form/416 0 R" images="110100"/>
<input type="radio"  tabindex="32"  id="form68_1" data-objref="495 0 R" name="rc-50" value="yes"  imageName="1/form/497 0 R" images="110100" checked="checked"/>
<input type="radio"  tabindex="31"  id="form69_1" data-objref="494 0 R" name="a2262at" value="no"  imageName="1/form/494 0 R" images="110100"/>
<input type="radio"  tabindex="17"  id="form70_1" data-objref="509 0 R" name="process" value="no"  imageName="1/form/509 0 R" images="110100"/>
<input type="radio"  tabindex="11"  id="form71_1" data-objref="503 0 R" name="master_glass" value="no"  imageName="1/form/503 0 R" images="110100"/>
  <input type="text"  tabindex="4"  id="form129_1" value="2" data-objref="62 0 R" title="Part No."  name="Part_No"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function process() {
  var form = document.getElementById('test');
  var elements = form.elements["Part_No"];
  var values = [];
  values.push(encodeURIComponent(elements.name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(elements.value) + "&frnm=MF001");

  form.action += '?' + values;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the server side script if anyone is interested.

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['Part_No'];
$nom = $_GET['frnm'];
ob_start();
$file = $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];
$time = microtime(true);
$newfile = "./customers/" . $nom . "." . $name . "." . $time . ".txt";
$worked = file_put_contents($newfile, $file);
ob_end_clean();
exit();

?>
```

Comment: There's no _text field with ID ""Part_No"_ ...

Comment: "<input type="text"  tabindex="4"  id="form129_1" value="2" data-objref="62 0 R" title="Part No."  name="Part_No"/>" Sorry, I meant name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of the radio button which has process or change the function name of the submit, i recommend change the function name as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="test" method="post" action="http://10.0.0.252/test.php" onsubmit="processForm()">
<input type="checkbox"  tabindex="40"  id="form67_1" data-objref="458 0 R" name="box_brown" imageName="1/form/416 0 R" images="110100"/>
<input type="radio"  tabindex="32"  id="form68_1" data-objref="495 0 R" name="rc-50" value="yes"  imageName="1/form/497 0 R" images="110100" checked="checked"/>
<input type="radio"  tabindex="31"  id="form69_1" data-objref="494 0 R" name="a2262at" value="no"  imageName="1/form/494 0 R" images="110100"/>
<input type="radio"  tabindex="17"  id="form70_1" data-objref="509 0 R" name="process" value="no"  imageName="1/form/509 0 R" images="110100"/>
<input type="radio"  tabindex="11"  id="form71_1" data-objref="503 0 R" name="master_glass" value="no"  imageName="1/form/503 0 R" images="110100"/>
  <input type="text"  tabindex="4"  id="form129_1" value="2" data-objref="62 0 R" title="Part No."  name="Part_No"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function processForm() {
  alert("test");
  var form = document.getElementById('test');
  var elements = form.elements["Part_No"];
  var values = [];
  values.push(encodeURIComponent(elements.name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(elements.value) + "&frnm=MF001");

  form.action += '?' + values;
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer.. Accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

It's like you try to append all form values to your action url in order to submit as GET... So why do you specify a POST method (in the form declaration)?

With no script at all... A GET method will allow you to retreive all your GET variables in PHP. If you want do do it as POST (so no value would show in the user's address bar), then retreive them with `$_POST['your field name']`.

Comment: I tried that a while ago, but it didn't seem get the data. Just tried it now and it worked. :/ Thanks.